# Returning BitmapDrawable in ImageView

Tags: android, imageview, mvvmcross

I am creating a list of favorites cars in Android app in MVVMCross. My problem is with dynamic loading images on that list. My point is that ImageView of per car is getting ID of picture which converter takes and returns BitmapDrawable object. It is working on my Windows Phone app, but in Android i have a little problem. Code looks like this:

```
<LinearLayout
      android:id="@+id/PeoplePanel"
      android:orientation="horizontal"
      android:layout_width="fill_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:background="@color/transparent"
      android:layout_below="@id/TitleTextView"
      android:paddingTop="3dip"
      android:paddingLeft="10dip">
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imagePhoto"
        android:layout_width="70dp"
        android:layout_height="70dp"
        local:MvxBind="{'ResourcesImagePath':{'Path':'Item.Obj.IDZdjeciaGlownego', 'Converter':'ByteToImg'}}"/>
```

and converter is:

```
public override object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
            {
                var id = (int?)value;
                if (id != null)
                {
                    var Service = this.GetService<IKomisSamService>();
                    var img = Service.GetImage((int)id);
                    try
                    {                
                        var drawable = BitmapFactory.DecodeByteArray(img, 0, img.Length);
                        return new BitmapDrawable(drawable);
                    }
                    catch { }
                }
                return null;
```

..and output:

```
04-12 11:13:06.034 I/MvxBind (  856): 135.42 Failed to create target binding for from Item.Obj.IDZdjeciaGlownego to ResourcesImagePath
MvxBind:Warning:135.42 Failed to create target binding for from Item.Obj.IDZdjeciaGlownego to ResourcesImagePath
04-12 11:13:06.034 I/mono-stdout(  856): MvxBind:Warning:135.42 Failed to create target binding for from Item.Obj.IDZdjeciaGlownego to ResourcesImagePath
04-12 11:13:06.644 D/dalvikvm(  856): GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed 1850 objects / 93880 bytes in 48ms
```

The converter is running twice: first for ask service to get item and when is downloaded it is running second time to get it and return BitmapDrawable object.

I assume that my problem is in MvxBind where i should not use ResourcesImagePath but other thing which get BitmapDrawable object not his path.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general:

- There are 'built-in' bindings in MvvmCross for displaying images from assets and from resources inside `ImageView`s
- The `MvxImageView` makes displaying downloaded images very simple - just use `ImageUrl` and ensure you have the DownloadCache and File plugins loaded.
- In v3, there is also a ready-made binding available for displaying `Byte[]` inside `ImageView`s (this is in the PictureChooser plugin)

However, for a general case where you want to add your own binding, then you can do this yourself if you want to...

But you can't do this just by inventing `ResourcesImagePath` and using a value converter. An `ImageView` doesn't have a `ResourcesImagePath` property - so the Mvx system has nothing to bind against in this case.

Instead:

1. You need to define the binding operation using a class like: https://github.com/slodge/MvvmCross/blob/vnext/Cirrious/Cirrious.MvvmCross.Binding.Droid/Target/MvxImageViewDrawableTargetBinding.cs
2. And you then need (during your `Setup`) to tell mvvmcross about how to use that binding - e.g. like on line 63 of: https://github.com/slodge/MvvmCross/blob/vnext/Cirrious/Cirrious.MvvmCross.Binding.Droid/MvxAndroidBindingBuilder.cs#L63

Doing this is called 'creating a custom binding'

---

*Note*: I'm not entirely sure about 'The converter is running twice' - not sure what you meant by this (sounds like a separate problem)

---

Important note - to avoid bitmap memory leaks, please use InPurgeable for all bitmaps that you load dynamically

Comment: Thanks for answer. I changed ImageView for MvxImageView. In output everything is working now fine - no error is shown. Nevertheless pictures still are not showing :( even with InPurgeable option. Any ideas? (In WindowsPhone the same idea is working great! The pictures are given to MvxImageView)

Comment: Using MvxImageView with ImageUrl is not enough? I though i could skip what you wrote after. Ok let's try this.